# Set a UIPickerView to bottom of UITableview regardless of scroll position

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I'd like to present a `UIPickerView` snapped to the bottom of a `UITableView` regardless of where it is scrolled.

Currently I have a `UIPickerView` added to a `UITableView` that I present when a button is pressed, but when I scroll the table the `UIPickerView` goes out of view, and if I'm scrolled out of range of where I've presented it, the `UIPickerView` appears to have never been called.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank

Comment: You need to set frame for UIPickerView and add as a subview of self.view..Not subview of UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something told me that there must be a simpler alternative to the answers that I'd been given, and I found a solution.

I decided to find the y coordinate of the scroll point using `scrollViewDidScroll:` and then animating the UIPickerView to the desired location.

```
    ...
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     CGFloat pointY = self.scrollPoint.y;
    [self.sortPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, pointY + 200, 320, 216)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    ...
```

The UIPickerView will only appear if the scroll has been stopped so it's necessary to implement a method to stop the scroll on touch:

```
- (void)stopScroll:(UITableView *)tableview
{
    CGPoint offset = tableview.contentOffset;
    [tableview setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}
```

This will allow you to display and dismiss the UIPickerView at any moment at any given destination.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `UITableViewController` is great unless you need to add subview that don't scroll with the table view. It can't really be done. The solution is to use a `UIViewController` instead and add your own table view, setup the table view dataSource and delegate protocols and replicate the basic table view controller plumbing.

Once your view controller works like a normal table view controller again, you can now add subviews to the view controller's view that won't scroll with the table.

Answer (score 0):

if u add tableview programatically

```
    SearchtableView.frame = CGRectMake(450, 90, 318, 600);
            SearchtableView  =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(623, 90, 400, 400)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            [self.view addSubview:SearchtableView];
//belove the tableview//
//Add UIPickerView to the self.view]//
```